# Would this restrict the class to be have a lifetime in the current frame only?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I wanted to restrict a specific class to be creatable on the stack only (not via allocation). The reason for this is that on the stack, the object which lifetime has begun last, will be the first to be destroyed, and I can create a hierarchy. I did it like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  static Foo createOnStack() {
    return {};
  }
  ~Foo () {
    std::cout << "Destructed " << --i << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  static int i;
  Foo () {
    std::cout << "Created " << i++ << std::endl;
  }
  Foo (const Foo &) = delete;
};
int Foo::i = 0;
```

The constructor normally should push the hierarchy stack, and the destructor pops it. I replaced it here for proof of concept. Now, the only way you can use such an object is by storing it in a temporary reference like this:

```
int main() {
  Foo && a = Foo::createOnStack();
  const Foo& b = Foo::createOnStack();
  return 0;
}
```

---

My question now is, how safe is this with the C++ standard? Is there still a way to legally create a `Foo` on the heap or hand it down from your function into another frame (aka return it from your function) without running into undefined behaviour?

---

EDIT: link to example https://ideone.com/M0I1NI

Comment: The committee is moving towards guaranteeing copy elision in certain cases such that `new Foo(Foo::createOnStack())` will become legal, so this is at the very least not future-proof.

Comment: @T.C. `new Foo(Foo::createOnStack())` would be illegal because of 8.5\16; 13.3.1.3\1; 13.3.3.1.4\1; 13.3.3\2; 3.2\3 "A constructor selected to copy or move an object of class type is odr-used..." and, eventually, 12.8\30. No?

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky I'm not saying it's currently legal. I'm saying that the committee is moving towards making it legal, via [P0135](http://wg21.link/P0135).

Comment: @T.C. Worse for them then : I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the `protected` backdoor, [C++17 copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) breaks this in **two** ways:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

struct S {
  static S make() {return {};}
  S(const S&)=delete;
  ~S() {std::cout << '-' << this << std::endl;}
private:
  S() {std::cout << '+' << this << std::endl;}
};

S reorder() {
  S &&local=S::make();
  return S::make();
}

int main() {
  auto p=new S(S::make()),q=new S(S::make());  // #1
  delete p; delete q;
  reorder();                                   // #2
}
```

1. The use of `new` is obvious and [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948403/would-this-restrict-the-class-to-be-have-a-lifetime-in-the-current-frame-only#comment57637679_34948403).
2. C++17 also allows prvalues to propagate through stack frames, which means that a `local` can get created before a return value and get destroyed while that return value is alive.

Note that the second case already existed (formally in C++14 and informally long before) in the case where `local` is of type `S` but the return value is some other (movable) type.  You can't assume in general that even automatic object lifetimes nest properly.

Comment: wandbox link for demonstration of the code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6Nt6zeS6ecKTYL28